# Place a Microsoft Access form into OLE container

Tags: .net, interop, ole

Simple question, in Visual Basic 6, you have the OLE container.

Is it possible to place a Microsoft Access form into a Visual Basic 6 OLE container? This is a follow on from [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564626/is-it-possible-to-host-a-microsoft-access-form-inside-a-net-form). I have figured out how to use an OLE container on a .Net windows form, so now I want to put a Microsoft Form into an OLE container.

Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

No. Access does not implement ActiveX document/OLE insertable interfaces.

You can try run Access as a hidden out of process COM server and provide your own UI, but mimicking the interface is not trivial work.